# Jackson fails on deserializing String to Joda-Time

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, jodatime

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.6 with Jackson 2.8.8. When deserializing the answer of a REST call, Jackson fails with the following exception:

> JSON parse error: Can not construct instance of org.joda.time.DateTime: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2018-03-19T12:05:21.885+01:00')

It's true there is no String constructor, only an Object constructor in the `DateTime` object.

I included the `jackson-datatype-joda` dependency in my build.gradle file. These are the respective lines from the build.gradle:

```
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: jacksonVersion
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: jacksonVersion
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat', name: 'jackson-dataformat-yaml', version: jacksonVersion
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-hibernate5', version: jacksonVersion
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-joda', version: jacksonVersion
```

Is there any additional configuration I need to do?

PS: If I put the date String into a `new DateTime("2018-03-19T12:05:21.885+01:00")` it works fine.

Any ideas? Cheers!

Comment: Please add the full exception stack trace and the`ObjectMapper` configuration. Otherwise it's guessing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Did you register the `JodaModule` module in your `ObjectMapper`?

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
```

Answer (score 0):

It has worked for me when I add the following dependency in build.gradle

compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-joda'